# How do I use the MediaRecorder API on processed audio?

Tags: wav, web-audio-api, web-mediarecorder

I am taking microphone input and processing it to do a FFT on the data, but the specifics of that are irrelevant for this question. A rough overview of my current code:

```
const microphone = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: false, audio: true});
const context = new AudioContext();
const stream = context.createMediaStreamSource(microphone);
const processor = context.createScriptProcessor(BUFFER_BYTES, 1, 1);
const analyser = context.createAnalyser();

// ...

stream.connect(analyser);
analyser.connect(processor);
processor.connect(context.destination);
```

I would also like to take this audio and record it into a `.wav` file. How can I do this? Is it possible to duplicate my microphone input stream such that I can process it via the nodes I am currently using, and record it via a [MediaRecorder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder?retiredLocale=nl) as well? Or can I simply add a MediaRecorder as a node in my audio pipeline?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `MediaStreamAudioDestinationNode` to get the processed audio as `MediaStream` again. It can be created like this:

```
const mediaStreamDestination = context.createMediaStreamDestination();
```

You can then connect your `processor` to the `mediaStreamDestination` as well.

```
processor.connect(mediaStreamDestination);
```

The stream provided by the `mediaStreamDestination` can then be used to create a `MediaRecorder`.

```
const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(mediaStreamDestination.stream);
```

Unfortunately no browser supports recording wav files out of the box. But I created a package which can be used to "extend" the native `MediaRecorder` with custom codecs. It's called [extendable-media-recorder](https://github.com/chrisguttandin/extendable-media-recorder). There is an example in the [readme](https://github.com/chrisguttandin/extendable-media-recorder#usage) which shows how it can be used to record wav files.